# Extract rows by rank and condition in R

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, rank

I am trying to understand how to extract the top ten rows from a table based on the values in one numeric column, but only from rows that meet a condition applied to a second numeric column.

 First about the data. I have a table listing, for a few thousand human genes, the difference in expression to a control (`log_fold_change`) and a p-value for this difference (`p_value`). The table looks something like this:

```
       log_fold_change   p_value
APOD         1.7388209 0.4820801
S100B       -1.1514299 0.5995658
CD63         0.6066951 0.4935413
PMEL        -1.4977796 0.1862176
MT2A        -0.9311173 0.8273733
S100A6      -0.4555436 0.6684667
TIMP1       -1.9464387 0.7942399
VIM         -0.4704482 0.1079436
PAEP         1.4787634 0.7237109
CSTB        -0.6386040 0.4112744
```

The data can be re-created using these commands (creates a table with data for `n` fictional genes):

```
n <- 50    
log_fold_change <- runif(n, -2.0, 2.0)
p_value <- runif(n, 0, 1.0)  
df <- data.frame(log_fold_change, p_value)
rownames(df) <- stringi::stri_paste(stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 3, '[A-Z]'),stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 1, '[1-9]'))
```

I have created a column for the labels (`df$label <- NA`), in which I plan to transfer the gene names that I want to label when I plot my graph. Which genes, you ask? I wish to, amongst genes with a positive `log_fold_change`, extract the ten genes with the smallest `p_value`.

I have already found a way to extract and label the 10 genes with the smallest `p_value`:

```
df$label[with(df, rank(p_value)) %in% c(1:10)] <- rownames(df)[with(df, rank(p_value)) %in% c(1:10)]
```

Now, how do I enforce the condition `df$log_fold_change > 0` so that my ten genes with the smallest `p_value` are only selected from the genes with a positive `log_fold_change`? Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order your data first, get the 10 values where `log_fold_change > 0` and transfer the rownames to `label` column.

```
df <- df[order(df$log_fold_change), ]
inds <- which(df$log_fold_change > 0)[1:10]
df$label[inds] <- rownames(df)[inds]
```

This will keep your original `df` as it is and you will have `label` only in those 10 rows.

If you want only those 10 rows you can do :

```
df1 <- df[inds, ]
```

Answer (score 2):

`dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  filter(log_fold_change > 0) %>%
  arrange(p_value) %>%
  head(10) %>%
  mutate(labels = rownames(.))
```

Output:

```
      A data.frame: 10 × 3
log_fold_change p_value label
   <dbl>       <dbl>    <chr>
0.9672121   0.01423086  MBT4
1.7139128   0.05044393  INQ3
0.4809652   0.10347463  ORW1
0.2949034   0.13493936  FVR2
0.9967781   0.17676960  JHP1
1.0813577   0.23599439  ITE9
1.0670343   0.25001069  ANQ4
1.5954271   0.26273176  XVL8
1.8803123   0.30065841  IQV6
0.3591054   0.46889062  JLD9
```

First you throw out all observations that are less or equal to `0` in the `log_fold_change` column with `filter(log_fold_change > 0)`. Then arrange the `p_value` column in ascending order with `arrange(p_value)` and select the first 10 observations with `head(10)`. Finally create the `label` columns with the names of the genes using `mutate()` . That gives you 10 observations with the lowest `p_value` where `log_fold_change` is positive.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R this could be achieved like so:

1. Split your df by `log_fold_change > 0`.
2. Set the labels separatly for each split
3. Bind back together

```r
n <- 50    
log_fold_change <- runif(n, -2.0, 2.0)
p_value <- runif(n, 0, 1.0)  
df <- data.frame(log_fold_change, p_value)
rownames(df) <- stringi::stri_paste(stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 3, '[A-Z]'),stringi::stri_rand_strings(n, 1, '[1-9]'))

df_split <- split(df, df$log_fold_change > 0) 
df_split[["FALSE"]]$label <- NA
df_split[["TRUE"]]$label <- with(df_split[["TRUE"]], rank(-p_value))
df_split[["TRUE"]]$label <- ifelse(df_split[["TRUE"]]$label %in% 1:10, row.names(df_split[["TRUE"]]), NA)
df <- rbind(df_split[["FALSE"]], df_split[["TRUE"]])

df[!is.na(df$label),]
#>      log_fold_change   p_value label
#> IPQ1      1.46479105 0.9928132  IPQ1
#> GDA3      0.26974526 0.9696272  GDA3
#> CHU3      0.31643010 0.7094205  CHU3
#> IDE1      0.87836008 0.7152144  IDE1
#> KQJ9      1.12647503 0.7854047  KQJ9
#> FQM8      1.99924827 0.8463336  FQM8
#> RPO1      0.10874876 0.7279679  RPO1
#> TOA9      1.88312825 0.7143039  TOA9
#> EXG7      1.82497903 0.8082063  EXG7
#> RGE9      0.02894958 0.7685504  RGE9
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>